# KDE Plasma - Disabling all animations without disabling compositor altogether

Tags: plasma, kde5

`System Information`:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 19.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.3
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.67.0
Qt Version: 5.12.4
Kernel Version: 5.3.0-40-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
Memory: 15,5 GiB of RAM
```

I want to disable all animations (or, if not possible, as many as possible) without disabling the compositor altogether (such as, by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>), so certain functionalities that require the compositor (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>) still work.

How do I do so?

Comment: By the way, elsewhere you wanted to know if "I can input a substring of a window's title and jump to that window?". You can. If you have several windows open and display them with `Ctrl+F9` and the display is very crowded, just type one or more relevant characters and a filter will be applied. Try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open *System Settings > Workspace Behavior > Desktop Effects* and disable individual effects with animations that you don't want. You will still have compositing active.

---

There is one more place to turn off some animations but this *could* be dependent on the theme. For example, with the defaults provided, open *System Settings > Application Style* and hover the mouse pointer over the style you're using. You may see a "pen" icon appear in the lower right corner of the style's box. Click on it. You may then see this:

**Turning off style-provided animations**

[image: Turning off style-provided animations]